# Defining delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text in which I would like to extract some data, but there is a problem: there are very similar parts, and this can cause confusion in the regex.

Example:

```
header
text
data: 10
body

header
text
data: 10
body
```

I'm simplifying, because I do not have permission to display the actual text

I want to extract the number after the `data`, but i need to delimit that it is between the header and the body. For this, I am using the regex:

```
header[\s\S]*?data:\s(\d+)[\s\S]*?body
```

working example: https://regex101.com/r/tS9gU6/1

But the text may not have the data, so it ends up taking the next:
https://regex101.com/r/hM7fV9/1

Is it possible to fix without using extra logic? I read something about "unrolling the loop"

Thanks.

Comment: So the text cannot include linebreaks? Or the header string? What else does keep the parts apart?

Comment: Have you tried to simply make it optional: `header[\s\S]*?(data:\s(\d+)[\s\S]*?)?body`?

Comment: If the text is in an HTML element it's best to do this with the DOM

Comment: See [`header.*(?:\n(?! *(?:data:\s\d|header *\n)).*)*\n *data:\s(\d+)[\s\S]*?body`](https://regex101.com/r/aL3iF9/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
header(?:(?!header)[\s\S])*data:\s(\d+)[\s\S]*?body
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zV2eE0/1)

Non-greedy quantifiers stop matching as early as possible, but they don't affect when the match starts.  Instead, you have to tell it to match anything except `header`.

Comment: This tempered greedy token will not match a valid string if there is a `header` text in between header and body. To make it safer I'd add an anchor or two with `/m`. But certainly unrolled pattern would be much nicer here  (for performance, too).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to misunderstand your question.

However, I guess this regex would work fine.

```
/header[\s\S]*?(?:data:\s(\d+)[\s\S]*)?body/g
```

I hope this post could help you.